# scrapy raise exception run from out side the project directory

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a scrapy project '**tutorial**' in the following directory

**C:\wamp64\www\tutorial>**

the project directory structure is given below.

[image]

I want to run the spider through my custom python script **runspiders.py**

```
from __future__ import print_function
  import scrapy
  from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
  from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


  def main():
      process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
      process.crawl("quotes")
      process.start()

  if __name__ == '__main__' : main()
```

The spider runs correctly when the custom python script run from inside the scrapy project folder e.g

**C:\wamp64\www\tutorial>python runspiders.py**

But the scrapy raise the following exception when the custom python script run from outside the project folder e.g

**C:\wamp64\www>python tutorial/runspiders.py**

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 43, in load
raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))
KeyError: 'Spider not found: quotes'
```

Answer (score 6):

Scrapy spiders are merely Python classes (subclasses of `scrapy.Spider`), so your script needs to know where to find those classes, like with any other Python class or module you use in your script.

**Inside a Scrapy project**, you have a `scrapy.cfg` file, which does at least 1 thing: it tells the framework where to find the project settings. For the tutorial project, it's `tutorial.settings`.

In the settings, Scrapy expects to have `SPIDER_MODULES` telling it which modules contain the spider classes. For the tutorial, this is `tutorial.spiders`.

When running your script inside the project, `get_project_settings()` does all this for you, to discover the settings module and reading `SPIDER_MODULES`, because there's a `scrapy.cfg` file.

**Outside the `tutorial/` folder**, you don't have a `scrapy.cfg`. And your Python script also probably doesn't know what `tutorial.spiders` would mean.

First, you can add `/path/to/tutorial/tutorial` to your [Python path](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonpath#envvar-PYTHONPATH) so that `import tutorial.spiders` would mean something.

But you also need to not rely on `get_project_settings()` since you're not in a Scrapy project folder. You can however change to

```
    process = CrawlerProcess({'SPIDER_MODULES': 'tutorial.spiders'})
```

(provided you've updated your Python path)

An alternative to look into is to use [`scrapy runspider /path/to/spider/module.py`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#runspider) which does not require a Scrapy project.

You may also want to read the [configuration options](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#configuration-settings) (with `scrapy.cfg` files elsewhere on your system) or about a [Scrapy project structure](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#default-structure-of-scrapy-projects).

Comment: For newcomers, in this answer the part about process = CrawlerProcess({'SPIDER_MODULES': 'tutorial.spiders'}) is very important.